# NativeProcess in adobe air with java with custom jar library

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript, air, native

I have a java code (New.java) which uses a custom java library (jcifs-1.3.17.jar).

And then what I need to do is to port the java code to adobe air using NativeProcess **WITH** the custom java library.

Here's a snippet of the code.

```
var info:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
info.executable = new File("/usr/bin/java/");
info.workingDirectory = File.applicationDirectory;


var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

args.push("-cp", ".://Users//angelo//jcifs-1.3.17");
args.push("-cp","../bin", "New");

trace(args);

info.arguments = args;

process = new NativeProcess();
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onDataOutput)
process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, exitFunc);
process.start(info);
```

After several tries of combinations for arguments I am still having errors porting the custom library, and when I tried it on command line it works just fine.

> java -cp .://Users//angelo//jcifs-1.3.17 New

Im having this error:
Cannot perform operation on a NativeProcess that is not running.

Apparently the NativeProcess executes the NativeProcessExitEvent upon execution of the code.

Comment: Please edit your post and include what these errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the custom jar file what I did was extracting the contents of the jar file and then added it to the project which would result to a single Main.class file after compilation which works fine.

But I still would have preferred adding the jar file itself on the action script.